# =ArrayFormula Using SumIf Function to Sum Between Two Dates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I am trying to **create a function that adds up all of the miles driven between two dates while using the** `=arrayformula` function to iterate down the column the results

Here is the syntax for my function below:

'TempDataSet'!G2:G: **sum range** that has the total miles driven

'TempDataSet'!C2:C: **criteria column** that has all the dates driven

A7: **Start Date**

B7: **End Date**

**This is the function I wrote below *using the sumifs function***

```
=SUMIFS('TempDataSet'!$G$2:$G,'TempDataSet'!$C$2:$C,">="&A7,'TempDataSet'!$C$2:$C,"<="&B7)
```

This function works, however I would like to implement the `=arrayformula` function so that the function can auto drag down the results.

I know **you can't use `=sumifs` while inside an `=arrayformula`, so this is where I am stuck

What is the way to do this using the `=sumif` function inside of an `=arrayformula`?

I've tried also using the `=query` function, but `=arrayformula` is not support with the =query function

Comment: Pls, give a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MMULT (if data are between row#2 AND #10)

```
=mmult(transpose(arrayformula(
IF((TempDataSet!$C$2:$C$10>=TRANSPOSE(A7:A))*(TempDataSet!$C$2:$C$10<=TRANSPOSE(B7:B)),
TempDataSet!$G$2:$G$10,0))),
sequence(rows(TempDataSet!$G$2:$G$10),1,1,0))
```

if you limit the number of rows in TempDataSet to avoid long calculations, you can also use

```
=mmult(transpose(arrayformula(
IF((TempDataSet!$C$2:$C>=TRANSPOSE(A7:A))*(TempDataSet!$C$2:$C<=TRANSPOSE(B7:B)),
value(TempDataSet!$G$2:$G),0))),
sequence(rows(TempDataSet!$G$2:$G),1,1,0))
```

### Explanation

- create a first matrix of conditions

  `=arrayformula(IF((TempDataSet!$A$2:$A$10>=TRANSPOSE(A2:A7))*(TempDataSet!$A$2:$A$10<=TRANSPOSE(B2:B7)),TempDataSet!$B$2:$B$10,0))`

[image]

- create a sequence of 1 : [sequence](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) (the number of columns is 1 and the number of rows is equal to the number of columns with the matrix that I have transposed)

  `=sequence(rows(TempDataSet!$B$2:$B10),1,1,0)`
- finally apply MMULT : [MMULT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094292)

Comment: This solved the problem! How does this work? I've never used MMULT, VALUE, or SEQUENCE before? I'm trying to understand arrays in Google Sheets.

Comment: I added some explanations, but I think you will find exercises on the web to better understand how mmult works!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER('TempDataSet'!G2:G; 'TempDataSet'!C2:C>A7; 'TempDataSet'!C2:C<=B7))
```